# After updating to iOS 8, Siri won't work with internal mic after first try

Tags: siri, ios

I’m seeing this problem:

Siri works fine the first time I try it after a restart, but on the second and subsequent tries, when I press and hold the home button, the screen turns gray and the microphone icon is displayed, but there's no sound and no wavy line indicating that input is occurring. The discussion is detailed [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6539863).  Some claim that Siri will only work via bluetooth. This appears to be happening on iPhone 5/5S hardware

Is there a workaround?

Comment: The reply in that thread that "Siri only works with bluetooth" is not official, it's just another users comment.   I have a 5s (that has been updated from 7 to 8) and don't have this problem, Siri is working fine for me.  ChrisCVB's answer in the thread you linked is interesting, and suggests a conflict.

Comment: I guess the fact that Siri works fine in certain cases explains why this wasn't caught during iOS 8 testing. By the way, I tried Siri over bluetooth this morning, and it worked. What's more is that doing this appears to have restored proper operation over the built-in mic.

Comment: my Siri works fine in iOS 8.0, but "Post to Facebook" feature is broken

Comment: What I’m seeing in iOS 8.1 is this: if I haven't used Siri in a while (several hours, or overnight), then when I invoke it by pressing and holding the home button, it doesn't appear to be receiving mic input. Sometimes I can get Siri working again by pressing and holding the home button repeatedly, but there are frequently situations where the only fix is a restart. This happens in situations where there is no bluetooth device around, so I don't think it's a conflict.
This is with an iPhone 5S that was replaced by Apple and was set up as a new phone.